# SQL query to extract incremental data from a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, t-sql, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am creating a AWS glue job to extract data from a OLTP database into redshift database. I want SQL query to extract incremental data from a table.
My table has columns like CreatedOn and LastUpdatedOn to track changes made in table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedOn] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [HasMiddleName] [bit] NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime] NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
    [Id] ASC
 )
)
```

Below is the query for full load

```
SELECT 
        Id
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreatedOn, 20) AS CreatedOn
        ,CreatedBy
        ,LastUpdatedBy
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, LastUpdatedOn, 20) AS LastUpdatedOn
        ,Type
        ,Title
        ,TRIM(REPLACE(FirstName,CHAR(10),' ')) AS FirstName
        ,TRIM(REPLACE(MiddleName,CHAR(10),' ')) AS MiddleName
        ,HasMiddleName
        ,REPLACE(Surname,CHAR(10),' ') AS Surname
        ,TRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateOfBirth, 20)) AS DateOfBirth
        ,Gender
    FROM
        table
```

Comment: Something to consider: Do you have a plan for handling deletes?

Comment: @TN judging by the code, i guess the answer is no

Comment: @TN no plans for handling deletes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the execution time for last successful job run and filter it as shown below

```
SELECT 
        Id
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, CreatedOn, 20) AS CreatedOn
        ,CreatedBy
        ,LastUpdatedBy
        ,CONVERT(VARCHAR, LastUpdatedOn, 20) AS LastUpdatedOn
        ,Type
        ,Title
        ,TRIM(REPLACE(FirstName,CHAR(10),' ')) AS FirstName
        ,TRIM(REPLACE(MiddleName,CHAR(10),' ')) AS MiddleName
        ,HasMiddleName
        ,REPLACE(Surname,CHAR(10),' ') AS Surname
        ,TRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DateOfBirth, 20)) AS DateOfBirth
        ,Gender
    FROM table
WHERE CreatedOn > '<LastSuccessful Job Execution Time>'
OR LastUpdatedOn > '<LastSuccessful Job Execution Time>'
```

Comment: I don't have any table which maintain last successful job execution time, Should I create a table which maintains the history of a job

Comment: Ideally you should have a meta table which drive your tables extraction.